# ng serve Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies

Tags: angular, api, symfony-3.3

> $ ng serve Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.
>
> Please take the following steps to avoid issues: "npm install
>   --save-dev @angular/cli@latest" You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.

in the backend(symfony) is run corretly but I had this error in angular js frontend when i want to run my server can someone have a idea why and how i solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may happen if you aren't in you root directory of your application. This can happen if you created a new project with the command `ng new project-name` and then try to run serve command without actually entering the created project directory.
1. Create a new project `$ ng new project-name` 
2. Enter the project directory `$ cd project-name` 
3. Only now run `$ ng serve`