# I can't create angular project

Tags: node.js, npm, angular5

i am facing a problem with angular 5. I downloaded angular 5 using command "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"..then when i try to the version of the angular using "ng -v" i receive this message
[image: here is the message]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng serve Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129772/ng-serve-unable-to-find-angular-cli-in-devdependencies)

Comment: how to solve it ?

Comment: npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest, this is not related to the angular cli installation. Do this command to remove older angular > npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you want to check the version of Angulsr CLI, you’d have to run:

```
ng —version
```

Hope this helps!